# Is $g(x^n)$ a convex function of $x$, if $g$ is a convex function of $x$ and $n>2$; given $x$ is nonnegative?

Tags: convex-analysis

Is $g(x^n)$ a convex function of $x$, if $g$ is a convex function of $x$ and $n>2$; given $x$ is nonnegative?

like $g(x^2)$ or $g(x^3)$

Comment: First, try to prove that is $f$ is convex nondecreasing and $h$ is convex then $f\circ h$ is convex. Then try to see why this is related to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try $g(x) = -x$.

You might do better if $g$ is also nondecreasing.

Comment: I got it.But reading some unedited literature out there misled me.

Comment: Thanks a lot. so, the answer is probably that for nonnegative x, x^n is convex, if g is non-decreasing convex, then g(x^n) is convex, right?

Answer (score 0):

A standard fact about convexity of composition is:

> If $f$ is a convex function and $g$ is a convex non-decreasing function of one variable, then $g\circ f$ is convex.

For a proof, see [The composition of two convex functions is convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/287716/).

This applies to your situation, if $g$ is also nondecreasing.