# Study the convexity of Mean Squared Error with regularization

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, neural-networks, non-convex-optimization

I want to study the convexity of the Mean Squared Error with regularization loss function. I am using an artificial neural network to compute the output.

$$E(w) = MSE(w) = \frac{1}{\mid D \mid}\sum_{d \in D} E_d(w)$$

$E_d$ is the error for a pattern $d$, defined as

$$E_{d}(w)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j \in outputLayer}^{} (t_{j}-o_{j}(w))^2 + \frac{1}{2}\lambda||w||^2$$

where $t_j$ and $o_j$ are respectively the target and the output of the $j^{th}$ output neuron of the network. $w$ are the parameters. $\lambda$
 is the regularization term.

**convexity study**

Intuitively I can say that the function is neither convex nor concave, since there are several local minima. In detail...

- $E_d(w)$ is a nonnegative weighted sum of two terms. This operation preserves convexity if the two terms are convex.
- The second term, $\frac{1}{2}\lambda||w||^2$, is convex since the squared euclidean norm is convex and $\lambda$ is positive.
- The first term, $\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j \in outputLayer}^{} (t_{j}-o_{j}(w))^2$, is neither convex nor concave because of the neural network...

for example, at the first layer of the neural network it is computed

$$g(x) = f(W \cdot x + b)$$

where $W \in R^{m \times n}$ is the first weight matrix, $x \in R^n$ is the network input, $b \in R^m$ is the bias and $f: R^m \rightarrow R^m$ is the element-wise activation function.

Here is when I break my analysis saying that the whole function is neither convex nor concave, depending on the activation function:

- if $f := identity$ then $g$ is convex on $R$
- if $f := ReLU$, then $g$ is convex on $R$
- if $f := Sigmoid$, the $g$ is convex in $R_-$ but concave in $R_+$
- if $f := tanh$, the $g$ is convex in $R_-$ but concave in $R_+$

I don't believe this analysis is sufficient, how can I improve it?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're trying to prove. As you note, in general, the (regularized) error function is non-convex--in other words, there exist activation functions $g$ which make $E$ non-convex. However, there _do_ exist activation functions $g$ which make $E$ convex (for example, if $g\equiv0$). So, what are you trying to show?

Comment: The goal is to know if E is convex or not, so that I know if some convergence properties of the learning algorithm I am using hold or not. Is my analysis complete enough to conclude that if I use ReLU as activation function then E is convex, otherwise for Sigmoid/Tanh is nonconvex?

Answer (score 2):

Here's at least a partial answer to what you're asking, I think.

You want to know whether or not the function $E$ is convex in $w$ if we take the activation function $f$ to be $\operatorname{ReLU}$.

The answer is no: consider a very simple network with two inputs (and a bias $b=1$) and one output. Suppose we have just one input pattern (*i.e.* $|D|=1$), which is the vector $x=(1,\ 1)$. Suppose the desired (target) output is $t=10$. The network is parameterized by the weight vector $w=(w_1,\ w_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. If we take $\lambda=1$, the error function is given by

\begin{align*}
E(w)&=\frac{1}{2}\big(t-\max\{w^\text{T}x+b,0\}\big)^2+\frac{1}{2}\lambda\|w\|^2\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\big(10-\max\{w_1+w_2+1,0\}\big)^2+\frac{1}{2}(w_1^2+w_2^2).
\end{align*}

However, we can plainly see that this function is not convex:

[image: Non-convex error surface for simple neural network]

Comment: This is a bit counter intuitive to me since ReLU is convex. Is there a way to check if a function is convex without plotting or checking if the Hessian is positive definite?

Comment: maybe by knowing the basic convex functions and knowing the operations that preserve convexity?

Comment: @ThanksBye that's a good idea. There are many such results. For example, the composition of two convex functions is not, in general, convex. But there are other useful results. [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/287716/398989) is one place to start.