# Convex/Concave functions composition counter-examples

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, examples-counterexamples, function-and-relation-composition

**(1)** If $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ are convex functions, then $f\circ g$ is convex. True or false? If not give a counter-example.

**(2)** If $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ are concave functions, then $f\circ g$ is concave. True or false? If not give a counter-example.

Clearly both statements are false. I computed a counter-example for each of them and I would like to know if they hold, please.

**(1)** Let $g(x)=x^2-1$ and $f(x)=|x|$. Both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are convex on $\mathbb{R}$. But, $f\circ g (x)=|x^2-1|$ is not convex on $\mathbb{R}$. So, the statement (1) doesn't hold

**(2)** Let $g(x)=-e^x$ and $f(x)=-x$. Both functions are concave on $\mathbb{R}$, but $f\circ g(x)=e^x$ is convex. So the statement (2) doesn't hold.

Comment: That is correct. Note that you can use $g(x) = -x$ to construct counterexamples for both statements.

Comment: @Martin R Alright, thank you very much for your feedback!

Comment: Your examples are correct. If you are interested in a general rule about composition of convex/ concave functions, check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287716/the-composition-of-two-convex-functions-is-convex).