# Find values for the function convexity

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, hessian-matrix

I have a function $$f(x)=\frac{-1}{2(1+x^Tx)}$$ and I need to find out for what values of $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ this function is convex and strongly convex.

I found the gradient
$$\nabla f(x)=\frac{x}{(1+x^Tx)^2}$$

and the Hessian matrix
$$\nabla^2 f(x)=\frac{1}{(1+x^Tx)^2} I-\frac{4xx^T}{(1+x^Tx)^3}$$

How can I find when my Hessian $\nabla^2f(x)\succeq 0$ and $\nabla^2f(x)\succeq \mu I$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287716/the-composition-of-two-convex-functions-is-convex

Answer (score 1):

For $x, z \in \mathbb R^n$ and we have
\begin{align*}
z^T \nabla^2 f(x) z
& = \frac{\| z \|_2^2}{(1 + \| x \|_2^2)^2}
- \frac{4 \| z^T x \|_2^2}{(1 + \| x \|_2^2)^3} \\
& \ge \left(\frac{1}{(1 + \| x \|_2^2)^2}
- \frac{4 \| x \|_2^2}{(1 + \| x \|_2^2)^3}\right) \| z \|_2^2 \\
& = \left(\frac{1 - 3 \| x \|_2^2}{(1 + \| x \|_2^2)^3}\right) \| z \|_2^2. 
\end{align*}
This term is nonnegative if and only if $\frac{1 - 3 \| x \|_2^2}{(1 + \| x \|_2^2)^3} \ge 0$, that is, $\| x \|_2 \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, so on the ball centered at the origin with radius $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, $f$ is convex.

For strong convexity, let $m \in [0, 1)$ be fixed.
We want to find out for which values of $x$, the function
$$
x \mapsto \frac{1 - 3 \| x \|_2^2}{(1 + \| x \|_2^2)^3}
$$
is lower bounded by $m$.
Note that it is upper bounded by 1, so we only consider $m \in (0, 1)$ in the sequel.

With $y := \| x \|_2^2 \ge 0$ this can be rewritten as
$$
1 - m - 3 m y - 3 y - 3 m y^2 - m y^3 \ge 0,
$$
which (as $m \in (0, 1)$) is, according to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve%201%20-%20m%20-%203%20m%20y%20%20-%203%20y%20-%203%20m%20y%5E2%20-%20m%20y%5E3%20%3E%3D%200%20for%20y%20%3E%200) equivalent to
$$
0 < \| x \|_2^2 \le \frac{1}{m}\left(2 m^2 + \sqrt{4 m^4 + m^3}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} - \left(2 m^2 + \sqrt{4 m^4 + m^3}\right)^{-\frac{1}{3}} - 1.
$$
When plugging in $m = \frac{1}{2}$ into the right hand side, the upper bound is approximately $0.1$, so that for $\| x \|_2^2 \le \frac{1}{10}$ the function is $\frac{1}{2}$-strongly convex.