# The composition of Convex functions?

Tags: functions, derivatives, discrete-mathematics, convex-analysis

My professor gave us the following question:

> Refute (with a simple example): Let ,:ℝ→ℝ be two convex functions.
> The composition ℎ≜∘ (that is, ℎ()=(())) is also a convex
> function.

But from what I can read online the composition of two convex functions is convex as well, what am I missing here?

[The composition of two convex functions is convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287716/the-composition-of-two-convex-functions-is-convex)

Comment: $g$ must be non-decreasing in your linked post.

Comment: @Aig ohh the title is misleading thanks, so in my counter example I should look for deceasing g but wasn't successful finding one, can u guide me? (I will do the proof)

Comment: $f(x)=-x$ is convex!

Answer (score 2):

Let $f$ and $g$ be $f(x)=-x$, $g(x)=x^2$. Then $f$ and $g$ are convex (since they are twice continuously differentiable and its second derivatives are $\geq 0$). However, $f(g(x))=-x^2$ is not convex.