# Is the following problem convex?

Tags: convex-optimization

I think the following problem is convex (due to the results of some simulations), but I am not sure:

$min_x||e^{(Ax)}-b||^2_2$ s.t. x>0

where $A$ is m x n, $x$ is n x 1, and b is m x 1. $A,x,b$ are all real. **The exponent of a vector means taking the exponent of each coordinate** (is there a better way to write this?).

My reasoning is as follows:

- $Ax$ is convex and $e^x$ is convex.
- Composition of convex functions is convex, so $e^{(Ax)}$ is convex.
- Subtraction shouldn't change convexity, so $e^{(Ax)}-b$ is convex.
- $||x||^2_2$ is convex so $||e^{(Ax)}-b||^2_2$ is convex due to convex composition.
- Restriction of variables to be positive won't change convexity.

Is this correct?

**1st EDIT:**

As justt indicated, my reasoning does not hold because convexity is not defined for vector-valued functions. I will try other approaches and update on my progress.

**2nd EDIT:**

For future reference, if anyone is trying to solve a similar problem: while this problem is not convex, it can be viewed as fitting the parameters of a log-linear model ($e^{Ax}$) to data ($b$). If $e^{Ax}$ is normalized into a probability distribution, then fitting the parameters using the MLE (Maximum Likelihood Estimator) approach **will** give a convex problem.

Comment: I don't agree that $Ax$ is convex and $e^x$ is convex. We can't say that a function is convex unless it is real-valued. You won't be able to use convex composition here.

Comment: You can define vector-valued convexity by the partial ordering over a closed convex cone of vectors. I don't know if that is helpful here, though.

Comment: @justt oh, did you mean the problem is that convexity is not defined for a function that maps a vector to a vector?

Comment: It's not true in general that a composition of two convex functions is convex. See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108393/is-the-composition-of-n-convex-functions-itself-a-convex-function)

Comment: @MattiÅstrand good point, although justt pointed out that convexity isn't defined anyway until the last step where I take the squared L2 norm. Also, $e^{f(x)}$ would be convex if $f(x)$ is convex, since $e^x$ is non-decreasing. Not sure about the second composition though.

Comment: The second composition does not preserve convexity. Monotonicity of the outer function is required.

Comment: As for the issue of convexity for vectors: just define it in an elementwise fashion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think about the case $m=n=1$: your function is just $(e^{ax}-b)^2=e^{2ax}-2be^{ax}+b^2$. It's pretty easy to find a counterexample where this is not convex.