# For a fixed positive definite $A$, is $(x,B) \to x^TB^{-1/2} A B^{-1/2} x$ always jointly convex?

Tags: operator-theory, convex-analysis, positive-definite, linear-matrix-inequality

Consider a real positive definite matrix $A\in R^{d\times d}$.
Let $S_d^+$ be the set of symmetric positive matrices.
Is it always true that
$$(x,B) \to x^TB^{-1/2} A B^{-1/2} x$$
is jointly convex in $(x,B)\in R^d \times S_d^+$?

It is true in the case $A=I$, see [Proving that $(x,Q) \mapsto \langle x,Q^{-1}x\rangle$ is convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1070011/proving-that-x-q-mapsto-langle-x-q-1x-rangle-is-convex/4806357#4806357) for instance for a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not even convex in $B$ alone:
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
,\quad
B_1 = \begin{pmatrix}  1 & 0.1 \\ 0.1 & 0.02 \end{pmatrix}
,\quad
B_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
,\quad
x_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0.5\end{pmatrix}
.$$

Plotting
$$
t \mapsto f(x, t B_1 +(1-t) B_2)
$$
for $t \in [0,1]$
yields a non-convex graph: [image: graph]