# Show that $f(\mathbf x)=e^{Q(\mathbf x)}$ is a convex function.

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, quadratic-forms

**Here's the problem:**

Let $A$ be a positive definite symmetric matrix and let $Q(\mathbf x)$ denote the associated quadratic form on $\mathbb R^n$. Show that $f(\mathbf x)=e^{Q(\mathbf x)}$ is a convex function.

**Here's what I know:**

I know that if the Hessian of some function is positive definite, then that function is strictly convex. I also know that, obviously, $f(x) = e^x$ is convex, so I would need only to show that $Q(\mathbf x)$ is convex. I don't know of any thing that says if $A$ is positive definite and symmetric, then its associated quadratic form is convex, but perhaps that's true? If so, how would I go about showing it?

Comment: Check [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/108394/26489) out.

Comment: Yes. I'd go so far as to say this is a duplicate (though admittedly in a roundabout way).