# Convexity of a function in two variables

Tags: real-analysis

I have the function $f(x,y)=e^{\alpha x^2+y^2}-1$. I want to find for which values is convex or not in its domain. If i find where $g(x,y)={\alpha x^2+y^2}$ is convex so the function   f is convex?

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: Almost an answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108393/is-the-composition-of-n-convex-functions-itself-a-convex-function

Comment: Look at the Hessian.

Comment: The hessian of f?

Comment: Yes. Or $g$. ${}{}{}$

Comment: $e^{g(x,y)}$ is convex if $g$ is convex?