# Show that the function $|t|^p$ is convex on $\Bbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb R$ be a function defined as $f(t) = |t|^p$ with $p\geq1$. I want to show that $f$ is convex by showing its second derivative is non-negative. I have tried calculating the second derivative but this led to confusion, is there a simpler way?

Comment: Can you describe some more the confusion you had?

Comment: Hi Sam. Please look at how I edited your post, to see how to type math. It will be helpful if you need to make changes.

Comment: I don't really understand how to actually compute this derivative, mainly due to the |t| part. But also what happens at t=0? since I am to show this property for all of t on R.

Comment: @Sam.S Use the chain rule.

Comment: @WillM. Yes but what is the derivative of |t| itself?

Comment: @Sam.S If $t > 0$ then $|t| = t$ and if $t < 0$ then $|t| = -t.$ At $t = 0$ there is no derivative. On a second thought, it may not be possible to follow your approach to prove it because $|t|$ has no derivative at zero.

Comment: @WillM. in that case, have you any idea how to show this result?

Comment: @Sam.S I've linked to the proof that the composition of an increasing convex function and a convex function is convex. More specifically it is this post https://math.stackexchange.com/a/473922/231327 I hope you might find it helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f:\Bbb R\to[0,\infty)$ defined by $$f(x)=|x|$$ is convex. Also, the function $g:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ defined by
$$
g(t)=t^p
$$ is convex and increasing for $p\ge 1$. [The composition of two such functions is convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108393/is-the-composition-of-n-convex-functions-itself-a-convex-function), hence
$$
|t|^p = g\circ f(t)
$$
is a convex function.

You can prove that $g$ is convex using derivative test as you want.

---

*Showing that $f$ is convex*: Take any $x,y\in\Bbb R$, we have
$$
|(1-\lambda)x + \lambda y| \le |1-\lambda||x| + |\lambda| |y| = (1-\lambda)|x| + \lambda |y|
$$
for any $\lambda\in[0,1]$, which show that $f(x)=|x|$ is convex.