# Check if the implication is true

Tags: real-analysis

> Let functions $f_{1}:I_{1} \rightarrow \mathbb R$ $f_{2}:I_{2} \rightarrow I_{1}$ where $I_{i}=(a,b)$ for $i=1,2$ $a,b \in \mathbb R$.
> If $f_{1}, f_{2}$ are convex then $f \circ g$ is also convex.

I think this implication is not truth so I'm looking for a counter-example for her.
However I have been doing this job for a long time and I have not been able to find anything.
Have you any ideas?

Comment: Not true in general, however with [sufficient conditions on $g$ it holds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287716/the-composition-of-two-convex-functions-is-convex). A counterexample can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108393/is-the-composition-of-n-convex-functions-itself-a-convex-function/108394).